# OSX (Yosemite) Make 2 sided printing the default for *all* applications

Tags: macos, printing

I'd like to make double-sided printing the default for **all** applications.  This [item](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/96366/can-i-make-double-sided-printing-the-default) tells how to set it for one application, but by experimentation it only affects that application, not others.  I Googled, looked in the system prefs, looked on this site - no luck.  Is there a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First save your print settings as a preset:

- Open a document, then choose File > Print. Click Show Details.
- Choose any print settings you want to save as a preset.
- Click the Presets pop-up menu, then choose Save Current Settings as Preset.
- Enter a name for the preset settings, then choose whether to use the preset for only the currently selected printer or all printers.

Then make that preset as default: hold the Option (alt) key when choosing your preset, and it will become Default.

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20131005034126/http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10768

Answer (score 10):

Thank you for that tip about the Option key. I spent some time solving this earlier today and here's another way: in a web browser, enter  http://localhost:631/printers in the address box and press Return. After the list of printers is returned, click on the printer in question. It took me quite a bit of poking around to find the setting for single-sided/double-sided as a default (Print Type: under "Finishing Options" tab). I suspect one advantage to this technique is that it sets the default in the *printer*, where the Option key method may only set it for that *print queue*. Since deleting and re-creating a print queue is a standard troubleshooting step, the web browser technique might be a better long-term solution.

Comment: Great solution. This worked on my Sierra.

Comment: Just tells me `'Web Interface is Disabled. The web interface is currently disabled. Run “cupsctl WebInterface=yes” to enable it.` And I don't want to turn that on just to change default settings of a printer. Apple, couldn't you make that a bit more discoverable?

Comment: @StefanHaberl, just enable it temporarily.

Comment: If the webpage asks you to sign in, just enter the username and password for your computer login.